# GLSL Gif Dither Effect: Optimization

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

[image: Image of shader result]

I've got a fragment shader that essentially reads the color alpha and translates it into a dithering effect across the pixels.

However, it's quite processor intensive with all the mods and if statements.
Does anyone have any recommendations on optimizing the code below?

```
varying vec2 the_uv;
varying vec4 color;

void main()
{
    // The pixel color will correspond
    //  to the uv coords of the texture
    //  for the given vertice, retrieved
    //  by the Vertex shader through varying vec2 the_uv

    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 tex = texture2D(_MainTex, the_uv);
    tex = tex * color ;
    float r = tex.a;

    if ( r > 0.1 ) {
        if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
    }

    if ( r > 0.5 ) {
        if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x + 2.0, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
    }

    if ( r > 0.7 ) {
        if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y + 2.0, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
    }

    if ( r > 0.9 ) {
        if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x + 1.0, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y + 1.0, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
    }

    if ( r > 0.3 ) {
        if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x + 2.0, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y + 2.0, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the solution based on the feedback:**

```
        varying vec2 the_uv;
        varying vec4 color;

        void main()
        {
            color = gl_Color;
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
            the_uv = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
        }
        #endif

        #ifdef FRAGMENT
        uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
        uniform sampler2D _GridTex;
        varying vec2 the_uv;
        varying vec4 color;

        void main()
        {
            if (texture2D(_MainTex, the_uv).a * color.a > texture2D(_GridTex, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y)*.25).a) gl_FragColor = color; 
            else gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);   

        }
```

Comment: You have very generic names for your variables. It would be a _lot_ easier to figure out what your algorithm is if you used more expressive names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to select whether each pixel should be lit on a 4x4 grid based on the source alpha. The simplest to do that is to do just that.

First initialize a 4x4 texture with the corresponding alphas that are required to have the pixel pass (I picked 1.0 as the alpha for never showing here)

```
1.0 0.5 1.0 0.1
1.0 1.0 0.9 1.0
1.0 0.3 1.0 0.7
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Setup this texture with repeat to avoid the mod completely, and a nearest filter to avoid linear filtering.

Then, use that a sampling of that texture to decide whether to light the pixel.

```
vec4 dither = texture2D(_my4x4, gl_FragCoord / 4.); // 4 is the size of the texture
if (r > dither) { gl_FragColor = color; }
```

This assumes that r is never 1. There are simple ways to work around that, e.g. divide the values in the 4x4 texture by 2, except the 1.0's, and then multiply dither by 2 before the if test, but after the fetch.

Some further potential optimizations:

- you can avoid the if test altogether by using a texture with comparison (shadow texture).
- you can avoid the /4 by using the textureFetch instructions

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your fragment color will be the same regardless of the results of the if statements since color is set at the beginning.

Secondly, using only if statements with no else if's makes your code run through each calculation no matter what.

A much better way to do this would be to have :

```
 if ( r > 0.9 ) {
    if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x + 1.0, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y + 1.0, 4.0) ) > 6.00) {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
}
else if ( r > 0.7 ) {
    if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y + 2.0, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
}
else if ( r > 0.5 ) {
    if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x + 2.0, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
}
else if ( r > 0.3 ) {
    if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x + 2.0, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y + 2.0, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
}
else if ( r > 0.1 ) {
    if ( ( mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 4.001) + mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 4.0) ) > 6.00 ) {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
}
else{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Of course this won't help you change the output since color is never changes (as I mentioned previously). But this should make things run a bit faster.

One other thing to take into account is what cases get executed most often. I assumed that the cases with large r are more common, hence the ordering of the if statements. If small r's are more common, then reversing the order and having r < 0.1, r < 0.3, r < 0.5, r < 0.7, r < 0.9 would make more sense.

The whole point here is to make the code exit as fast as possible (i.e. have one of the if's return true). Once one of the if's returns true, the rest are ignored, saving you from calculating all the rest of the mod operations.

Comment: "First of all, your fragment color will be the same regardless of the results of the if statements since color is set at the beginning." That's not true. You can set shader stage outputs multiple times; only the last one is taken. You can even do in-place modifications to them.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant is that since color is assigned outside the if loops, the result of each individual if loop will be the same regardless of which one is true (r > 0.9 gives the same frag color as r > 0.1). (Unless there is something completely wrong with my understanding of how shaders work).

Comment: But they only set that color if they have that additional `mod` condition. Otherwise, they just use the default color of 0. It's not just `r > X`.

Comment: I'm still missing it... Isn't color just taken from the vertex shader and never modified?

Comment: Unless the conditions are _false_, in which case, the color will be `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`.

Comment: I can't use an else-if because it's possible for all of the If statements to be true. I've attached an image of what the result looks like. I think the optimization will come in the mod statements.

Comment: So it seems Nicol's and mike's comments rendered this answer completely invalid.